# Access query fields to be equal

Tags: ms-access

I am teaching a guy to polish matura and they have to use Access sometimes.

I have a table with columns `pyt_1`, `pyt_5`. I would like to display only these rows in which these columns are equal.

In SQL it looks like that:

```
SELECT pyt_1, pyt_5
FROM Ankiety
WHERE pyt_1=pyt_5;
```

but he has to know how to do it in query design

I chose the `pyt_1`, `pyt_5` column and added criteria `pyt_1 = pyt_5` but ACCESS automatically converts it into string, how to avoid that?

He converted my SQL into query design but it's weird.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is that you write `= pyt_5` into the criteria field for the column `pyt_1`, and Access automatically converts it into `= "pyt_5"`, correct?

If yes, you need to put `pyt_5` in braces (`[ ]`).
This makes the Access query editor recognize it as a column name.

Here is a screenshot (German Access version with German labels, but you get the idea):

[image: access query]